# How to markup email address and telephone number

Tags: html

Using html5 semantics, what is the correct way to markup a contact part of a page i.e.:

```
<div class="contact">
    <h3>Contact me</h3>
    <p>Telephone: <span>01111 1111</span></p>
    <p>Email: <span><a href="mailto:me@me.com">me@me.com</a></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the link:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2011/08/01/html5-part-1-semantic-markup-and-page-layout.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You could use [microformats](http://microformats.org/get-started) or microdata (e.g. using the syntax of [schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html)) both are supported by the major search engines.

I can't say for sure which is the standart, because the time i looked a this there where many discussions around them. But think it is microdata that should be used. Personally i prefere microdata because they are more flexible with more options, and don't use classes.

**EDIT**
Here are the specs for microdate from [whatwg](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html) and the draft of [w3c](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/microdata/master/)

Example using microdata with *schema.org* syntax

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <p>Telephone:  <span itemprop="telephone">01111 1111</span></p>
  <p>Email: <a href="mailto:me@me.com" itemprop="email">me@me.com</a></p>
</div>
```

For completion also an example with microformats:

```
<div class="vcard">
    <p>Telephone:  <span class="tel">01111 1111</span></p>
    <p>Email: <a class="email" href="mailto:me@me.com">me@me.com</a></p>
</div>
```